# Referencing Multiple Cell Values in Different Rows in Excel, Tied to the Values in that Row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of names (column A) along with a month that they did not turn in an assignment (column B).  My goal is to identify current and *consecutive* repeat offenders (column C).

Column C highlights green (Keep) if the month is current.
Column C highlights red (Delete) if the month is *not* current **AND** there is more than one entry for the same name (so they have not failed to turn in the assignment for the last two months).

If they have failed to turn in the assignment for multiple months in a row (including this month), is there a way I can have the spreadsheet automatically identify that there are multiple values for the name AND at least one of those rows for that specific name is in the current month?

```
=IFS([@Month]=$H$2, "Keep", AND([@Month]<>$H$2, (COUNTIF(A:A,A2)=1)), "Delete", AND([@Month]<>$H$2, (COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1)), "Review")
```

Comment: Some sample data would help explain exactly how your formula is working or not working.

Comment: try using a pivot table, put both the names (column A) and months (column B) in the 'Rows' section, ungroup the months, and maybe change the view of the pivotable to tabular form, you will have a clear view of the 'repeat offenders'